# Lambda (Python 3.6) PyMySql Query EXISTS query always returns 1

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, aws-lambda, slack-api

I am trying to get a PyMySQL query in Lambda (Python 3.6) to return whether a user exists or not. I pass my slack user ID into the query. This is what I want to check in MySQL. I can run the same query through MySQL and it returns a 0, but for some reason, every time I call this query through lambda, it tells me the user exists (My database is empty). My query is function is this:

```
def userExists(user):
    statement = f"SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM slackDB.Assets WHERE userID LIKE '%{user}%')Assets"
    tempBool  = cursor.execute(statement, args=None) 
    conn.commit()
    return tempBool
```

Here is the full code I am working with:

```
################################
# Slack Lambda handler.
################################

import sys
import logging
import os
import pymysql
import urllib

# Grab data from the environment.
BOT_TOKEN   = os.environ["BOT_TOKEN"]
ASSET_TABLE = os.environ["ASSET_TABLE"]
REGION_NAME = os.getenv('REGION_NAME', 'us-east-2')

DB_NAME     = "admin"
DB_PASSWORD = "somepassword"
DB_DATABASE = "someDB"
RDS_HOST    = "myslackdb.somepseudourl.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com"
port        = 3306

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

try:
    conn = pymysql.connect(RDS_HOST, user=DB_NAME, passwd=DB_PASSWORD, db=DB_DATABASE, connect_timeout=5)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
except:
    logger.error("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to MySql instance.")
    sys.exit()

# Define the URL of the targeted Slack API resource.
SLACK_URL = "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage"

def userExists(user):
    statement = f"SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM slackDB.Assets WHERE userID LIKE '%{user}%')Assets"
    tempBool  = cursor.execute(statement, args=None) 
    conn.commit()
    return tempBool

def addUser(user):
    statement = f"INSERT INTO `slackDB`.`Assets` (`userID`, `money`) VALUES ('{user}', '1000')"
    tempBool  = cursor.execute(statement, args=None) 
    conn.commit()
    return tempBool

def lambda_handler(data, context):
    # Slack challenge answer.
    if "challenge" in data:
        return data["challenge"]

    # Grab the Slack channel data.
    slack_event    = data['event']
    slack_userID   = slack_event["user"]
    slack_text     = slack_event["text"]
    channel_id     = slack_event["channel"]
    slack_reply    = ""

    # Ignore bot messages.
    if "bot_id" in slack_event:
        slack_reply = ""
    else:
        # Start data sift.
        if slack_text.startswith("!networth"):
            slack_reply = "Your networth is: "
        elif slack_text.startswith("!price"):
            command,asset = text.split()
            slack_reply = f"The price of a(n) {asset} is: "
        elif slack_text.startswith("!addme"):
            if userExists(slack_userID):
                slack_reply = f"User {slack_userID} already exists"
            else:
                slack_reply = f"Adding user {slack_userID}"
                addUser(slack_userID)

        # We need to send back three pieces of information:
        data = urllib.parse.urlencode(
            (
                ("token", BOT_TOKEN),
                ("channel", channel_id),
                ("text", slack_reply)
            )
        )
        data = data.encode("ascii")

        # Construct the HTTP request that will be sent to the Slack API.
        request = urllib.request.Request(
            SLACK_URL, 
            data=data, 
            method="POST"
        )
        # Add a header mentioning that the text is URL-encoded.
        request.add_header(
            "Content-Type", 
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        )

        # Fire off the request!
        urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()

    # Everything went fine.
    return "200 OK"
```

I am typing '!addme' in slack and it always tells me the user exists. I have printed out my query statement and it is inputting my slack ID correctly. I have checked my table, and it is completely empty. I have run the query in MySQL and it returns a 0.

Does anyone have any ideas? Am I just derping this up on something easy? Any helps or hints is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a `fetch` from the cursor. Just the `execute`.

And the return from `execute` is the number of rows affected. For DML operations (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) that makes sense. But I wouldn't rely on the rows affected count for a SELECT.

In this case, the `SELECT EXISTS` query is going to either return a row, or throw an error. But the fact that the query returns a row doesn't tell us anything about the value of the `Assets` column.

From the query, it looks like we want to fetch a row, and then determine if the `Assets` column contains a 0 or 1 (or NULL).

After the query execution,  try  `cur.fetchone` to retrieve the row.

---

We could also execute a simpler query, and then use a fetch to determine if a row is returned or not.

Comment: cursor.execute(statement, args=None)
tempBool  =  cursor.fetchone() Tried this just now and it returns no errors (yay!), but it always returns 1 every time. Any ideas?

Comment: So fetch returned a row. Which is what we expect.  `SELECT EXISTS` is going to return a row. What matters is the content of the row... is the `Assets` column equal to 1 (at least one row found), or is it equal to 0 (no row was found.)  This is where we can simplify things... ditch the SELECT EXISTS wrapper, and just run the query that returns a row (if one is found), or doesn't return a row (when a row is not found.) We can add a LIMIT 1 clause to avoid returning more than one row, all we care is if a row is returned. And then we can just use the return from `fetchone`.

Comment: If we are going to insist on using a `SELECT EXISTS` query, we need to actually fetch the row, and examine the rows that is returned. We'd need to get the value of `Assets` column.

Comment: Thanks! I will try ditching the SELECT EXISTS and adding LIMIT 1. Appreciate the explanations.